# Simple Macro Failing in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

Are simple macros sometimes incompatible with TikZ?

I am making a whole bunch of graphs whose formatting I would like to control from the preamble.

But this seemingly trivial endeavor fails in the code.

What's happening? Why does the first `TikZ` picture work while the second fails?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}


% THIS IS THE MACRO THAT FAILS
\newcommand{\BlueLine}{line width = 2.8pt, blue, opacity=0.35}


\begin{document}

% THIS COMPILES
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width = 2.8pt, blue, opacity=0.35] (0.3,-3)--(7,3);
\end{tikzpicture}


% THIS DOES NOT COMPILE  
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[\BlueLine] (0.3,-3)--(7,3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: for this purpose `tikz` define styles. so instead `\newcommand{\BlueLine}{line width = 2.8pt, blue, opacity=0.35} ` you should define style: \tikzset{BlueLine/.style={line width = 2.8pt, blue, opacity=0.35}}`

Comment: @Zarko: Sorry, didn't see your comment about the style

Comment: well, meanwhile i convert it to my answer (because i didn't see your answer :( what to do?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, but i vote yours ... :)

Comment: @Zarko: Yes, as I have done for your one...

Comment: @Zarko: Removed the reference of `styles` in my answer, so we have too independent answers

Comment: @Zarko: I meant two independent answers of course ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, that is beter :9

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for this purpose tikz define styles. so instead

```
\newcommand{\BlueLine}{line width = 2.8pt, blue, opacity=0.35}
```

you should define style:

```
\tikzset{
    BlueLine/.style={line width = 2.8pt, blue, opacity=0.35}
         }
```

and than use as:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\tikzset{
    BlueLine/.style={line width = 2.8pt, blue, opacity=0.35}
         }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[BlueLine] (0.3,-3)--(7,3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you! I can only give the check mark to one person, though... the two answers appear to me to be roughly equivalent, though, right?

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything, well, what you select is up to you. i can only advice you to read answer about how people define `tikz` elements (lines, shapes) styles and what is suggested in (huge) tikz & pgf manual.

Comment: and by the way, answers are different, one solve your problem, another advice how to avoid your problem :). in this particular case the result is the same.

Answer (score 8):

The `\BlueLine` macro is not expanded in the usage of `\draw`.

One way to force this is `\expandafter\Draw\expandafter[\BlueLine] ...;`

Another one is to define styles (as has been done in Zarko's answer)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}


% THIS IS THE MACRO THAT FAILS
\newcommand{\BlueLine}{line width = 2.8pt, blue, opacity=0.35}



\begin{document}

% THIS COMPILES
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width = 2.8pt, blue, opacity=0.35] (0.3,-3)--(7,3);
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\expandafter\draw\expandafter[\BlueLine] (0.3,-3)--(7,3);
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What does `\expandafter` mean?

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything: `\expandafter\foostuff\foobar` will expand `\foobar` first and then `\foostuff, such that `\foostuff` can 'evaluate' the expanded version of `\foobar`, with other words: I puts expansion of the current command sequence on hold and looks for next one after that to expand

Comment: Ok. That will take me a while to digest... Your answer seems more general than the other one. Given that it's only a few keystrokes, why would `TikZ` impose restrictions on the expansion of macros in `\draw`?

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything: This is actually not a TikZ problem -- almost any key-value interface has this issue, `l3keys` from upcoming LaTeX 3 format has some means to force expansion before.

Comment: Isn't it tokens? If you say `\expandafter\foostuff.\foobar`, it won't expand `\foobar` before `\foostuff`, will it? Even though `\foobar` is the next command sequence.